# Error .Net VB -- The remote server returned an error: (501) Syntax error in parameters or arguments

Tags: .net, vb.net, ftp

I write a piece of code just for testing to send txt file with type ASCII to FTP server, but keep getting following error.

### The remote server returned an error: (501) Syntax error in parameters or arguments.

I am sure the user name and password is correct, and I tried to set UsePassive true and false but get same error.

The following is the code I used.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Net

Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim lPOSByteArray() As Byte
    Dim lEncoding As New ASCIIEncoding
    Dim lPOSFlatFile As String
    lPOSFlatFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\\Users\\somebody\\Desktop\\Test.config.XML")
    lPOSByteArray = lEncoding.GetBytes(lPOSFlatFile)

    Dim lFTPrequest As System.Net.FtpWebRequest

    lFTPrequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("ftp://" & "199.222.111.111" & "/" & "Test.txt"), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
    lFTPrequest.Proxy = Nothing
    lFTPrequest.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("userxxx", "passyyy")
    lFTPrequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile
    lFTPrequest.UseBinary = False
    lFTPrequest.UsePassive = True
    lFTPrequest.ContentLength = lPOSByteArray.Length

    'ERROR happened on following line
    Dim lFTPrequestStream As Stream = lFTPrequest.GetRequestStream()
    lFTPrequestStream.Write(lPOSByteArray, 0, lPOSByteArray.Length)
    lFTPrequestStream.Close()

    Dim response As System.Net.FtpWebResponse = DirectCast(lFTPrequest.GetResponse(), System.Net.FtpWebResponse)

End Sub
```

End Module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your code is right. The problem is in another place, like network or ftp server. I tried with my FTP server and changed the line

```
 lPOSByteArray = lEncoding.GetBytes(lPOSFlatFile)
```

to

```
 lPOSByteArray = lEncoding.GetBytes("test")
```

and works fine. Can you read/write this file with a ftp client like FileZila?

Comment: Thanks for you quick help. Yes, u are right, the problem is cuased by network. I tried my code from anohter domain. It partially works. I said it partially works, becuase it only send first 81 characters of each line of the file. Do you have any idea about this issue?

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem here. I create one file and assigned to "lPOSFlatFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\test.log")" and works. This file is a simple text with 100 chars/line. When do you read xml, all content goes to lPOSFlatFile?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time, Jonathan. Yes, lPOSFlatFile will keep the whole XML file as a long string with ASCII format, I have check the contents of this string, it do keep all characters. But after I check the uploaded file on FTP server, every line of file are there. But every line only has 81 char, if it's longer than 81 chars. If i found the reason of it, i will update this post.

Comment: For my understanding, the "problem" may caused by IBM MainFrame FTP. It will only accept files with certaion formats with length limitation of each line in the file.

Comment: I tried, when i use binary, all screwed. only get unreadable string.